# How to resolve "No column was specified for column 1 of 'r'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query is

```
select *
from (
    select rtrim(Emp.s_filterh)
    from Emp, Dept
    where Dept.label = 'xyz' and Emp.filtery = 1 and Emp.r_id = Dept.r_id  
    order by 1 desc offset 0 rows
) as r
where ROW_NUMBER() < 26
```

when I run this, I am getting

> No column was specified for column 1 of 'r'

As I read for the error that we should be providing Alias but in my case even after providing alias query is throwing error.

Edit : I'm trying to use ROW_NUMBER() to limit the number of rows fetched.

Can someone let me know what is going wrong

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is not a standalone keyword, it is a function.  It is not clear what you are trying to do here.  Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Order by 1. There is no column called 1. What is the ordering you want?

Comment: And best practice is to use explicit joins - not implicit joins as you have done.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :  ROW_NUMBER() is being used to limit the number of rows returned by this query (As we have ROWNUM in Oracle)

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `row_number` and then [edit] any clarifications into your question.

Comment: @DaleK : You simply ignored the first part of the question and downvoted for the second half and now even if I edit the question it won't allow any answers. Good job!

Comment: @m_beta you'll note that 3 people voted to close your question - not just me. If you improve your question then people can vote to reopen. However Tim appears to have provided a possible answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just give alias to your column as follows:

```
select * from (select rtrim(Emp.s_filterh) my_column_name from Emp, Dept
    where Dept.label = 'xyz' and Emp.filtery=1 and Emp.r_id=Dept.r_id  
    order by 1 desc offset 0 rows ) as r
    where ROW_NUMBER < 26
```

**Note**: Always use the standard ANSI joins.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Providing alias to the column resolved the first error.
ROW_NUMBER() is being used  to limit the number of rows returned by this query (As we have ROWNUM in Oracle)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` to retrieve the first 26 rows, then use this syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RTRIM(Emp.s_filterh),
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RTRIM(Emp.s_filterh) DESC) rn
    FROM Emp e
    INNER JOIN Dept e ON d.r_id = e.r_id
    WHERE d.label = 'xyz' AND e.filtery = 1
) t
WHERE rn < 26;
```